# Change main website site url from http to https

Tags: wordpress, url, https, multisite

I found a similar topic but it didn´t solve my problem. I installed a WordPress Multisite. I changed all the values manually that are described in endless forums and tutorials.

My Website > Network > Website > Edit > Info
--> Here the site url stays with http (See pic)

My Website > Network > Website > Edit > Settings
--> Here the site url and home have been changed to https (See pic)

Why?

I checked my changes endless times. The changes should be all correct and done where they should. Still the main site url stays at http what I don´t understand. I have done the changes regarding to this tutorial and others:

https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/

Also I put in the values

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://somedomain.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://somedomain.com' );

just to be sure! It didn´t do anything so I deleted this last part again.

Can u please help me. This is so frustrating.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6KQu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from the German wordpress.org site helped me out with a link form Stack Exchange. So in case someone had the same issue, here is a possible solution that helped me out. That´s his words regarding to this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/355888/129212

"Workaround:

1.) Make a backup of the database. No backup, no pity.

2.) In wp-config.php, comment out the code block for multisite with the prefix // in front of each line (do not delete).

Analogous:

```
// define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
// define ('MULTISITE', true);
// define ('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
// $ base = '/';
// define ('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
// define ('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
// define ('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
// define ('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

3.) Login again and change the URL to https://example.com (with your domain) under Settings > General

4.) In the wp-config.php delete in the code block the comment characters // for multisite.

Analogous:

```
define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define ('MULTISITE', true);
define ('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
$ base = '/';
define ('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define ('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define ('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define ('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

5.) Carry on as if nothing had happened."

He said that it seems that WordPress didn´t consider that the main page / parent page would change in any way. So it is the easiest way to return with the previous steps to a "normal site", change the urls and then "activate" Multisite again.

Hope it helps! See ya!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org), you can also use the `wp network` command to update the meta value:

`wp network meta update 1 siteurl https://somedomain.com/`

The `1` is your network ID, which is 1 by default.

Alternatively, you can update the database entry directly if you don’t use any object cache:

```
UPDATE wp_sitemeta SET meta_value = 'https://somedomain.com/' WHERE meta_key = 'siteurl';
```